# How to transfer only part of the balance of the contract?

Tags: solidity

If there is an Ether of 100 in the contract, I would like to send only Ether of 5 from here. Is it possible?

Not like this.(witout '%')
`payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance / 20);`

I'd like to send only the size specified.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean but, just compute the specified amount as unit of wei and transfer it.

```
uint256 amount = 5 ether  // 1 ether is equivalent to 1e18 wei
payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be noted that .transfer and .send have been deprecated for a while now, and can be a pain with out of gas issues.

the recommended method is .call
it's also recommended that you code checks for the success/failure of call.

e.g.

```
uint _amount = 5 ether;
(bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: _amount}();
require(success, "payment failed");
emit Paid(msg.sender, _amount);  // event defined elsewhere
```